# Issue in Passing Url in PHP

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am doing some operation in URL as below.

```
 $paginationPages=array();
 $productCount=intval($htmlProductPage->find('div.paging span.itemcount',0)->plaintext);
 if($productCount/16>1){
    $pagecount=ceil($productCount/16);

    for($i=2;$i<=$pagecount;$i++){
        $urlSplitArray=explode('.',$productUrl);
        $urlSplitCount=count($urlSplitArray);
        $urlSplitArray[$urlSplitCount-2].="[".$i."]";
        $paginationPages[]= implode('.',$urlSplitArray)."<br>";
    }
 #print_r($paginationPages);

}
```

and I am getting all the links in foreach to proceed further

```
foreach($paginationPages as $nextUrl){
  #$nextUrl="http://www.100percent.co.nz/kitchen-and-cooking/ovens/freestanding[2].htm";
  $htmlProductPage=file_get_html($nextUrl);
  foreach($htmlProductPage->find("div.Item") as $element){ //error occurs here
    echo $element->outertext;
  }
}
```

The variable `$nextUrl` has the value

> "http://www.100percent.co.nz/kitchen-and-cooking/ovens/freestanding[2].htm"

I cant find the element `div.Item` when I pass the link dynamically. But when I directly assign the url inside the for loop I could able to find the same element. Why this is happening?

Comment: Where is the error occurring -- is your code successfully getting the page using `file_get_html`?

Comment: @ialarmedalien please check my updated question. I have mentioned where the error occurs

Comment: The link is commentted inside the for each loop

Comment: An example URL for this bit of code: `$urlSplitArray=explode('.',$productUrl);` - what is $productUrl?

Comment: http://www.100percent.co.nz/kitchen-and-cooking/ovens/freestanding.htm since it has pagination i need to add '[2]' before the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring due to this statement:

```
$paginationPages[]= implode('.',$urlSplitArray)."<br>";
```

print_r of `$paginationPages`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.100percent.co.nz/kitchen-and-cooking/ovens/freestanding[2].htm<br>
)
```

You are tagging a `<br>` element on to the end of the page name, which then means that the page cannot be retrieved with this code:

```
foreach($paginationPages as $nextUrl){
    $htmlProductPage=file_get_html($nextUrl);
```

I suggest adding a check that `file_get_html` has successfully retrieved a page before parsing the page to scrape the contents.

Comment: No probs. Sometimes it takes another person to track down a typo like this!